# Does Istio allow to configure a maximum response timeout for a circuit breaker to open? How?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, circuit-breaker

I'm checking the [documentation for the DestinationRule](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/destination-rule/), where there are several examples of a circuit breaking configuration, e.g:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-app
spec:
  host: bookinfoappsvc.prod.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      tcp:
        connectTimeout: 30ms
          ...
```

The connectionPool.tcp element offers a connectTimeout. However what I need to configure is a maximum response timeout. Imagine I want to open the circuit if the service takes longer than 5 seconds to answer. Is it possible to configure this in Istio? How?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Tasks --> Traffic Management --> Setting Request Timeouts:](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-timeouts/)

> A timeout for http requests can be specified using the timeout field
>   of the [route rule](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/#HTTPRoute). By default, the timeout is 15 seconds [...]

So, you must set the `http.timeout` in the `VirtualService` configuration.
Take a look at this example from the [Virtual Service / Destination](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/#Destination) official docs:

> The following VirtualService sets a timeout of 5s for all calls to
>   productpage.prod.svc.cluster.local service in Kubernetes.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-productpage-rule
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - productpage.prod.svc.cluster.local # ignores rule namespace
  http:
  - timeout: 5s
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage.prod.svc.cluster.local
```

> [http.timeout:](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/#HTTPRoute) Timeout for HTTP requests.

Comment: Hi Eduardo, is that `http.timeout` setting taken into account in the circuit breaker? Supposing I have configured `outlierDetection.consecutiveErrors: 4`, do 5 consecutive timeouts open the circuit?

Comment: @codependent I think this will be helpful [Istio Circuit Breaker With Outlier Detection](https://dzone.com/articles/istio-circuit-breaker-with-outlier-detection)